# Can't send messages from RabbitMQ with Go

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I just started reading about `RabbitMQ` and I'm trying to send large number of messages in a for loop. The problem is that it just doesn't work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var connectionString = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/"
    conn, _ := amqp.Dial(connectionString)
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, _ := conn.Channel()
    defer ch.Close()

    q, _ := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "user_actions", // name
        true,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )

    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        body := "Hello from Go! " + strconv.Itoa(i)
        ch.Publish(
            "",     // exchange
            "hello", // routing key
            false,  // mandatory
            false,  // immediate
            amqp.Publishing {
                ContentType: "text/plain",
                Body:        []byte(body),
            })
        fmt.Println("Sent: "+body)
    }

}
```

I even tried reducing the number of iterations and even tried sending messages outside of the loop but it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The provided code seems fine except that you are using the default exchange and providing a route name different than your queue name.

Chances are you'll want to use the queue name as the routing name. Try to replace `hello` with `user_actions` in `ch.Publish` function.

Comment: If RabbitMQ can't route a message (as in your case), the message is dropped. I highly recommend going through the RabbitMQ tutorials for Go: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html